# Поиск хорошего шаблонизатора

Tags: php, шаблонизаторы

Снова нахожусь в поиске хорошего шаблонизатора.

Очень понравился XTemplate своей идеологией, однако скорость его оставляет желать лучшего.
С кешами я еще не разбирался.

Есть ли что то аналогичное, но с более быстрой обработкой?

Сразу говорю Twig, Blitz не предлагать. У них разная идеология.

Comment: А что за "идеология" у XTemplate? чем так хорош проект под РНР4, который заморозился больше 3-х лет назад?

Comment: Блочный с отделенным синтаксисом от html.

Comment: Поднимаю тему т.к. вопрос еще открыт. Сейчас смотрю в сторону написания велосипеда в стиле XTemplate. Хотелось бы заодно узнать мнения по поводу этого решения.

Comment: Свой шаблонизатор лучше всего же.

Comment: @Сергей Я придерживаюсь такому мнению: В шаблонизаторе не должная быть описана сложная логика (к примеру, циклы) - в последний случае, нет ничего лучше нативного решения, ибо для тех же верстальщиков, ИМХО, сложная логика неприемлема.

Как Вы смотрите на синтаксис [шаблонизатора CMF MODx][1] (надстройка над Smarty)? Популярность этой CMF как раз-таки обусловлена использованием подобного синтаксиса.

Если Вас устроит подобное решение, но только без "тяжеловеса" Smarty, то следите за постами на хабре в ближайшую неделю. Впрочем, могу и здесь отписаться.
  [1]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/122289/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> С кешами я еще не разбирался.

Тогда путь дорога лежит именно в этом направлении, раз другие не подходят, а кэшировать нужно!

Answer (score 2):

Я в шаблонизаторах не очень, т.е я ими не пользуюсь, но во многих движках видел btemplate. Может попробуйте, удачи!

Comment: увы не подходит, идеология не та

Comment: Больше незнаю, удачи в поисках. =)

Comment: А какая по вашему должна быть идеология у хорошего шаблонизатора? я например начал юзать twig, прям насладиться не могу.

Comment: Прошу прощения заголовок изменили без меня. Насчет твига еще раз говорю он не подходит для моих целей.

Answer (score 2):

Twig очень крутой. И идеология у него вполне себе крутая!))
Ах! Ну да, у него еще и синтаксис совместим с django, это если Вы захотите свой проект переписать на python, Вам нужно будет только модели и вьюшки написать, а представление будет готово уже)

Answer (score 0):

[Smarty](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smarty) неплох...

Comment: Увы плох. Тем что идеология не та.

Comment: @Сергей, а  использовать просто HTML, религия не позволяет ? ))

Comment: недостаточный функционал